# Browser Cancels PUT requests

Tags: xmlhttprequest, cors, axios

I've got a rails api and a react front end with axios to interact with the api. Have enabled CORS in rails, but the below request gets cancelled by the browser and can't find the reason for it.

Request copied as "fetch" call:

```
fetch("http://localhost:3000/api/v1/profile", 
    {
        "credentials":"include",
        "headers":{
            "accept":"application/json, text/plain, */*",
            "accept-language":"en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8",
            "authorization":"Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiIxIiwic2NwIjoiYWNjb3VudCIsImF1ZCI6bnVsbCwiaWF0IjoxNTg2OTY4MjIwLCJleHAiOjE1ODcwNTQ2MjAsImp0aSI6IjhkNTE2YjIzLTA1MGQtNGU2MS04ZWE1LWM3ZGIwMzkxNTg0NCJ9.KuwtVNB5minrOs3lvfNjt7lVQSWNRXdqZsbErb6SrGM",
            "content-type":"application/json",
            "sec-fetch-dest":"empty",
            "sec-fetch-mode":"cors",
            "sec-fetch-site":"same-site"
        },
        "referrer":"http://localhost:3001/profile?",
        "referrerPolicy":"no-referrer-when-downgrade",
        "body":"{\"first_name\":\"testsdasd\",\"last_name\":\"asadeesdfsfs\"}",
        "method":"PUT",
        "mode":"cors"
});
```

Is this getting cancelled due to CORS? BTW other post requests are getting through.

Thanks a lot.

Below is the code using axios.

```
async updateProfileData(profile) {
        try {
            let axiosResponse = await AxiosClient.instance().put('http://localhost:3000/api/v1/profile', {
                first_name: profile.first_name,
                last_name: profile.last_name
            },{
                headers: {
                    "Content-Type": "application/json"
                }
            });
            return axiosResponse;
        } catch (e) {
            return e.response;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Code shows fetch, not axios

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Found the answer.

```
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at ‘http://localhost:3000/api/v1/profile’. (Reason: Credential is not supported if the CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ is ‘*’).
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS/Errors/CORSNotSupportingCredentials?utm_source=devtools&utm_medium=firefox-cors-errors&utm_campaign=default

Comment: Authorization Header with CORS seems to be not accepted by the Browser.

Comment: What does that solve? How come POST was working then?

Comment: the post was for the authentication, which doesn't include the Bearer token. hence it passed through.